# Dynamic FROM IRI in SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, ontology, dbpedia

I'm doing a task in SPARQL where I want to link my ontology to dbpedia to get the publishing date of various games. For each game in my ontology I've added properties linking to the dbpedia resource (`:dbPediaEntry`), and the publishing year described in that resource (`:dbPediaPublishYear`). This because there is no common structure on how these fields are described in dbpedia (e.g., it's called "`years`" for some resources and "`firstReleaseDate`" for others). My query therefore looks like this:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX : <MY_ONTOLOGY_IRI>
SELECT ?dbPediaPublishYear
FROM <http://dbpedia.org/page/Mastermind_(board_game)>
FROM <MY_ONTOLOGY_IRI>
WHERE { 

    :MasterMind :dbPediaEntry ?dbPediaEntry.
    :MasterMind :dbPediaPublishYear ?dbPediaPublishYearPredicate.

    ?dbPediaEntry ?dbPediaPublishYearPredicate ?dbPediaPublishYear.

}
```

And it works as expected. However, the only way I've been able to make it work is with the line `FROM <http://dbpedia.org/page/Mastermind_(board_game)>`. That means I have to manually change this IRI every time I switch game. That same IRI is stored in the `?dbPediaEntry` variable, but that variable cannot be accessed outside the `WHERE` clause (that I know of). Is it any way to make the IRI after `FROM` be dynamic, and determined by a variable? I though of using nested queries, but it doesn't seem like it's possible to add a `FROM` in a nested query.

Comment: that is correct, subquery doesn't allow for specifying datasets. Federated querying via `SERVICE` keyword and using the public DBpedia endpoint might be an option, but it would need some federated query engine being smart enough to pass the values into the federated query request. Option 2) you could use a `VALUES` clause and the public DBpedia endpoint to fetch the relevant data for all your games. This would just need to create the `VALUES` clause once via some script.